# Save the result of an expression to be used in a separate block

Tags: perl, variables, store, substitution

As you can see, I want to store the result of the first substitution in `$enkel`. I use this `$enkel` in the print of `if`.

But when I want to use this `$enkel` in the `elsif` print, it has no value. I actually want to use both `$dubbel` and `$enkel` in the `elsif` print.

Is there a way so that Perl stores this permanently in `$dubbel`, so it can be used in other prints?

```
if ($inputwoord =~ /((aa|uu|ee|oo)[^aeiour])$/) {
  ($enkel = $inputwoord) =~ s/([aueo])\1/$1/g;
  print "$enkel$buig\n$inputwoord$gen\n$enkel$comp\n$enkel$compe\n$inputwoord$sup\n$inputwoord$supe\n";
}
elsif ($inputwoord =~ /[^aeiou][aeiou]([pktgnmlf])$/) {
  ($dubbel = $inputwoord) =~ s /([pktgnmlf]$)/$1$1/g;
  print "$dubbel$buig\n$inputwoord$gen\n$dubbel$comp\n$dubbel$compe\n$inputwoord$sup\n$inputwoord$supe\n";
} # consonantgeminatie
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can understand and run it. Help us to help you.

Comment: Please don't add comments (like asterisks) to the code itself. The code should stand by itself, and any commentary should be in the text of the question. It is important that we can see the code that *you* are running

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't have `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your program? Either that, or you are defining all your vaeiables in a block at the beginning. You *must always* have `use strict` and `use warnings`, and variables should be declared using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use.

Answer (score 1):

You must calculate the value of `$enkel` outside the `if` statement if you want to use it in both the `if` and the `elsif` clauses. Like this

```
($enkel = $inputwoord)  =~ s/([aueo])\1/$1/g;
($dubbel = $inputwoord) =~ s/([pktgnmlf]$)/$1$1/g;

if ($inputwoord =~ /((aa|uu|ee|oo)[^aeiour])$/) {
  print "$enkel$buig\n$inputwoord$gen\n$enkel$comp\n$enkel$compe\n$inputwoord$sup\n$inputwoord$supe\n";
}
elsif ($inputwoord =~ /[^aeiou][aeiou]([pktgnmlf])$/) {
  print "$dubbel$buig\n$inputwoord$gen\n$dubbel$comp\n$dubbel$compe\n$inputwoord$sup\n$inputwoord$supe\n";
} # consonantgeminatie
```